# Can you change a hero's save slot?

Tags: fable-3

I'm moving saved games from one system to another.  I've created heroes on both systems and as a result, have two saves named "Hero 1" (one on the hard drive, the other currently on a memory stick).  I was able to move the non-conflicting saves over just fine.

Can I change the save slot somehow?  If I could "rename" the save currently on the memory stick from "Hero 1" to "Hero 3", I could move it over and have all my saves in one place.  As it stands, it looks like I have to either keep them split across storage devices or overwrite one of my heroes.

Comment: I know for certain it can't be done in _Fable II_, so I doubt they will let you move your file in _Fable III_.